# Redirect::back() returning an empty url in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I want to redirect back user to entered url after authenticating user
Scenario is: User enter a url, in backend I check for user to be authenticated and if user does not authenticated redirect user to login url and after successful login redirect user back to first url that user entered

Users Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    if(!Auth::check())
    {
        return View::make('adminLogin');
    }
    return Redirect::to('admin');
}

public function login() 
{
    $creds = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

    if (Auth::attempt($creds))
        return Redirect::back();
}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

Route::post('login', 'UsersController@login');
```

filters.php:

```
Route::filter('logged', function($request)
{
    if(!Auth::check())
        return Redirect::to('users');
});
```

SettingController.php:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('logged', array('only' => array('index')));
}

public function index()
{
    return View::make('setting');
}
```

Please help me.I'm a newbie in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Redirect::intended('/');` instead of `Redirect::back();`.

PS: Also change

```
Route::filter('logged', function($request)
{
    if(!Auth::check())
        return Redirect::guest(URL::to('users')); //Your login form.
});
```

Comment: I test it out.it's just redirect user back to root url.for example if I entered this url: http://example.com/settings, after login I want to redirect back to this url

Answer (score 0):

use the `intended()` method

`The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.`

example :  `return Redirect::intended('/');`

Comment: I believe `redirect()` is not available in 4.2.